# Will the Phottix Odins for Sony give me remote power control over a LumoPro LP180?

Tags: flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash, phottix

### Context

So I have a Sony α6300 with a Metz 64 with the Sony Phottix Odin Wireless setup. With that setup, I have no problems and TTL works just fine.

### Question

I'm considering adding a second light, a LumoPro LP180 (not the LP180R). I know that the Phottix has options to control the power of the light. Given the LumoPro is a full manual flash, is there anyway to control it via the Phottix or is it just a dumb "fire" command from the wireless trigger?

I'm assuming the answer is a no but I wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the LP180R, a Sony α6000, and the Phottix Odin II for Sony MIS. I got a firmware update from Lumopro which allows the LP180R to be put into Odin Sony Rx mode. The Odin II gives full manual control over flash power and zoom, and does give HSS option. Seems to work on fill flash, slow sync, rear curtain, and wireless settings on the α6000.

However, there seems to be a problem with TTL—it does not seem to work correctly, and changing the exposure setting on the Odin II has no effect, as far as I can see.
I contacted Phottix, and their response was that they do not offer support for third party flashes. Interestingly, on the download page of the Phottix website, the PDF instruction manual for the Odin II for Sony was not available the last time I checked (the Odin II came with instructions on USB).

I wrote to Lumopro a week or so ago, asking if there was a known problem, but have had no response.
I am guessing there *is* a problem, as Lumopro are not advertising their firmware upgrade on the website or blog, and their LP180R PDF instructions on their website still do not mention anything about the Sony Rx option.
I am hoping they (Phottix? Lumopro?...) can resolve the issue. I thought you might like to hear my experience with the Odin II /LP180R combination.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback there. Luckily Godox makes their own flashes that actually do work for Sony so I'll be opting for the TT685S. It's not as great of a build as the LP180R but since it's a backup light i don't mind it as much. There's also a V860IIS if you want to use Li-po instead of AA.

Answer (score 0):

The LumoPro LP180 is a "dumb" manual-only single-pin flash. It has no built-in radio receiver, and no way to control its power remotely, so all an Odin can do is trigger it.

The newer LumoPro LP180**R**, however, is still a single-pin manual-only flash, but has a built-in Odin/Strato receiver, and through the receiver, *can* have its power and zoom settings remotely controlled by an Odin.

---

Addendum:

Looks like the LP180R may not work for the Sony version of the Odins. Maybe consider the [Godox X1S](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Remote_Control_X1S_TTL_Wireless_Flash_Trigger.html) triggers and a [TT600S](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Camera_Flash_TT600S.html) to tide you over until LumoPro comes out with an LP180R that does? :) Of course, then you'd have to wait for the Sony receiver to come out in the X1 system. (sigh).

Comment: Single-pin being the center "button" on the flash? I wish the Lp180R can help me but I'm using the Sony wireless setup. The LP180R supports Canon and Nikon but not Sony, at least what the specs say. I don't know if that means I can control it or not.

Comment: No "single-pin" meaning only a single pin on the foot for the sync/fire signal of the hotshoe--that signal is universal across all iso-compliant hotshoes (like Sony's multi-interface hotshoe). Not sure about the TTL compatibility, though. But I'd guess that as long as the Odin can signal, it should at least let you do manual sync with power control. Maybe contact LumoPro?

Comment: From what I read about the Odin, they have different wireless frequencies between the different camera versions of the wireless triggers, e.g. Canon, Sony and Nikon. Since it does not support Sony, the LP180 and LP180R would operate the same as the Odin on my camera cannot communicate to it right?

Comment: @unsignedzero I don't know. I'm not a Sony shooter. They could also have written that description before the Sony Odins came out...

Comment: That's the problem I had. I asked LumoPro and they can't confirm nor deny anything. From what I've read the Phottix site states they are separate. I'll assume the answer is sadly no unless someone else has first hand experience. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42565/discussion-between-unsignedzero-and-inkista).